# Mathematical prediction of synchronizing multiple cams.

Tags: classical-mechanics

I am not a mathematician so be gentle with me but what kind of math equations (or what *field* of mathematics) would be needed for the following:

I have designs for an old-style mechanical device I am creating with a complex set of [cams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cam) -- a total of 62 of them! and I am trying to figure out how to predict how frequently the cams will all synch simultaneously to their starting position (i.e.: how often the overall complex pattern will repeat).

[image: animated cam illustration]

- Each cam has its own unique rotation speed (generally the larger diameter ones are slower to complete one full rotation) but that speed is 100% reliable as all of the cam shafts are fed by a single MAIN drive shaft that is then geared to the various cam shafts. Essentially each cam rotates at a percentage of the MAIN shaft's rotation speed. That percentage can be over or under 100% of MAIN.
- Each cam has a "starting position" or "zero point" and when the device is first activated each cam is reset to zero point.
- Each cam is built as a simple circle with a different/unique radius (there "cam" effect is caused by a wavy groove on the side of each cam that transmits a pattern to an embedded armature).

So what is the required math to take these various cams's data and predict how long (i.e.: how many rotations of the MAIN drive shaft -- one full rotation = one heartbeat if you will) it will take for all of the cams to return simultaneously to zero point? For simplicity's sake lets talk about the math for only a few (3? 4?) cams (I assume this math can be expanded later to address 62 cams or more).

Answer (score 3):

You want to work out the lowest common multiple of the periods of rotation of each cam.

Mathematically you are trying to solve:

$$p_i\times n_i=t \text{ for } i=1\to62$$ where $p_i$ is the period of cam $i$, $n_i$ is how many times it rotates (an integer) and $t$ is the time taken. You are looking to minimize $t$.

Consider an easier problem as an example: One cam take 2 minutes to rotate and a second takes 3 minutes to rotate and a third which takes 4 minutes to rotate. The lowest common multiple of 2, 3 and 4 you get 12. After a total of 12 minutes the first will have done exactly 6 rotations and the second done exactly 4 rotations and the third done exactly 3 rotations. No smaller amount of time will satisfy the problem.

EDIT: If you aren't sure how to find the lowest common multiple of 2 or more numbers just post a comment.

Comment: Interesting, It seems like a pretty simple concept but I guess it can be pretty involved finding the LCM for 62 variables. And while I am not a mathematician I think I remember LCM's and GCF's from my early college algebra days (*he says as the sound of rust creaks in his brain*) ... it has something to do with prime factors if I recall correctly. :)

Comment: Yes. First you can write each number as the product of powers of prime numbers. E.g. $45=3^2\times5$ Then you can then just find the largest power of each prime across all 62 numbers. E.g. if the numbers are $24,45,150$ then $24=2^3\times3, 45=3^2\times5, 150=2\times3\times5^2$ and so the LCM is $2^3\times3^2\times5^2=1800$

Comment: A quick google search turned up numerous sites for working out LCM. None could manage with 62 random numbers between 1 and 200. Google also turned up many 'prime factorization calculators' which would allow you to do one number at a time then look at the powers.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I tried much the same and I also tried Excel's builtin **=LCM()** function which can handle 255 numbers as input but even using straight increments of 1 for my inputs the LCM function couldn't handle more than 40 numbers (result > 2^52). It seems this is going to require a minor bit of programming in [a language that allows arbitrary-precision large numbers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/131107/handling-extremely-large-numbers-in-a-language-which-cant).

Comment: If you have the 62 numbers you could post them as a new question. There would be a number of users here who have arbitrary-precision calculation software. (I'm curious how mine would go :) )

Comment: I am still working out the bugs on the rotation speeds (some of the gearing is not quite right) but once it runs smoothly I can do that. Much appreciated..